# Getting “Error: Resolution method is overspecified”? in beforeEach and afterEach

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, knex.js, chai-http

When I use done in `beforeEach` or `afterEach` I get this error `“Error: Resolution method is overspecified”` and the test fails.

But now if remove the `done()` all my tests pass but the terminal hangs without exiting the test script.

I am using knex.js as a query builder.

Is there a solution to this problem?

```
beforeEach(async (done) => {
  await db.migrate.rollback(migrationConfig);
  await db.migrate.latest(migrationConfig);
  await db.seed.run(seedConfig);
  done();
});

// cleaning db before running tests
afterEach(async (done) => {
  await db.migrate.rollback(migrationConfig);
  done();
});

describe("POST /user/login", () => {
  it("should return a jwt after loging in user", (done) => {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .post("/user/login")
      .send({
        email: "saaransh@test.com",
        password: "test123",
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.should.be.json;
        res.body.should.have.property("token");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `async` handler functions, then you should not give it parameter `done`. Promise returned by async function will tell Mocha when executing the function is ready.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await db.migrate.rollback(migrationConfig);
  await db.migrate.latest(migrationConfig);
  await db.seed.run(seedConfig);
});

// cleaning db before running tests
afterEach(async () => {
  await db.migrate.rollback(migrationConfig);
});
```